# NumPy Reads Binary Data Incorrectly?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with a binary file "uint64.bin" whose entire contents can be represented by: 0x0f2d1e6002df9000

My python code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_dtype = np.dtype([('mytag','>u8')])
with open("uint64.bin", 'rb') as fh:
    data = np.fromfile(file=fh, dtype=my_dtype)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.dtype.names)
print(df.get_values()[0])
```

What prints is 1093563682234798080 whereas the output should be 1093563682234798100 (the difference is in the 0x14 bits). What's going on?

I'm on Windows 64-bit and using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `print(0x0f2d1e6002df9000)` in Python.  It gives you:

```
1093563682234798080
```

So the answer you're getting is correct, your assumption about what it should be is incorrect.